# Can sqoop run without hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

Just wondering can sqoop run without a hadoop cluster? sort of in a standalone mode? Has anyone tried to run sqoop on spark, please share some experiences on it.

Comment: Given that it's a tool for transferring data to/from Hadoop, what good would it do on its own? StackOverflow isn't a polling site - "share some experiences" isn't a valid on-topic question around here.

Comment: sqoop2 is not a tool just transferring data to/from hadoop. There are cases, sqoop move things around outside hadoop.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To run Sqoop commands (both `sqoop1` and `sqoop2`), Hadoop is a mandatory prerequisite. You cannot run sqoop commands without the Hadoop libraries.

Sqoop works in local mode too, so it is not a requirement that the Hadoop daemons must be running. To run sqoop in local mode,

```
sqoop [tool-name] -fs local -jt local [tool-arguments]
```

Sqoop on Spark is still In-Progress. See [SQOOP-1532](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-1532)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess, performance wise, running in local mode is pretty much like running a data loading job in a single process.